# PMMA vs PVC for opal led strip enclosures?

Tags: lighting, led, pvc

I am planning to install some aluminium profiles for led strips with matte cover diffusers ( opal / frosty).  I found that the covers are made from two different types and I would like to know the pros and cons.

Mostly I am interested if there are any signifiant light loses, degradation in time (like getting yellowish). Fire dangers are probably out of question as they are both graded for this use and they are using aluminium profile.[image: pmma-vs-pvc-opal]